# Handle form with Angular: error doesn't show

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have simple  form. I need to show errors about my fields.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
    <head></head>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">

        <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
            <input type="text" ng-model="field" name="myField" />
            <div ng-show="myForm.myField.$error" style="color: red">
                {{myForm.myField.$error}}
            </div>
        </form>

        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="controller.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my controller

```
angular.module('MyApp',[])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function() {
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        var error = {
                myField: 'Error in this field'
        };
        for (var key in error) {
            form[key].$error = error[key];
        }
    });
```

Why I can't see error about myField? I get only '{}'

Comment: In AngularJS **NEVER** access DOM like `document.getElementById("myForm")` in a `controller` you are sure to be in a bad way and you will soon struggle. Controller manages Model not VIEW and Directive manages VIEW. Now there is simple way managing form validation in AngularJS please have a look at this [easy tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation). It will help doing it even better and easier than you imagine.

Answer (score 0):

You're not binding the form to AngularJS correctly

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
```

This says your form is called `myForm`, so in your controller you should be using `$scope.myForm`

No need for `var form = document.getElementById("myForm");`, just use `$scope.myForm` in your controller

Try this to see if you access the the form from AngularJS

```
angular.module('MyApp',[])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.myForm.myField.$error = "just to see it work";
});
```

Comment: did you inject $scope in the controller?

Comment: @Bob yes see the code snippet in my answer, thanks to the edit of  Tomasz Bawor who added $scope to the controller

Comment: Of course i inject $scope, but the result doesn't change. I am getting error.